# Slide-In effect on TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, splash-screen

I'm trying to create a window much like the SplashScreen in Microsoft Office products. These start with a slide-in from left to right, combined with a fade-in of the product name.

How can I accomplish such an effect in WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spend some time with the documentation for wpf's animation system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

There's some good examples there, like this one which will continuously fade a rectangle in and out:

```
<Rectangle
  Name="MyRectangle"
  Width="100" 
  Height="100"
  Fill="Blue">
  <Rectangle.Triggers>
    <!-- Animates the rectangle's opacity. -->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" 
            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```